# Optimizing DRF performance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to optimize a DRF view that has very low performance, is there a way to make it faster? This is where I am right now

Models:

```
class CategoryVideos(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} and {self.id}"

class Videos(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(CategoryVideos, null=True, blank=True)
    illustration = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True) 
    video = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    url_video = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    url_image = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

Serializers:

```
class CategorySerializer2(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CategoryVideos
        fields = ["name"] 

class VideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    category = CategorySerializer2(many=True, read_only=True) 

    class Meta:
        model = Videos
        fields = ["id", "description", "title", "url_video", "url_image", "category"]
        read_only=True
```

View:

```
class OfferListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset  = Videos.objects.prefetch_related('category').all()
    serializer_class=VideoSerializer
```

For the moment, with 400 videos and just 6 categories, it takes approx 2.8 secs to get an answer which is way too high.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you are using only for **listing** you can add
**db_index=True** attribute for any field you can also use db_index=True to create an index on a ForeignKey and ManyToManyFields for performance.
make note that creating indexes can slow down the performance of some database operations, such as inserting or updating large amounts of data.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. I just put the whole thing in prod environment and it drastically reduced the response speed, from 2.8 to 0.17, still looking to lower it though because those 400 videos could rise to 6K so looking into caching the whole thing